# How to search by all fields Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, search, model-view-controller

I would like to know, how can i write the method in my dao file to get all objects matching some regular expression? How to implements search by all fields exclude field group?

For example, user enters a text fiels and gets list of objects of class Teachers matching the condition {there can be some symbols}{userText}{there can be some symbols}.

How can i get around all fields exclude group

**This is my entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="teacher", schema = "public")//, schema = "public"
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Teacher extends Human implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="teacher_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Group.class,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "teacher_groups",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "group_id") })
    private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList();//<>

    public List<Group> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }
    public void setGroups(ArrayList<Group> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    public void addGroup(Group group){

            if (!(this.groups.contains(group))){
                groups.add(group);
            }
    }

    public void removeGroup(Group group){
        for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++) {
            if (groups.get(i).getId().equals(group.getId()))
                groups.remove(i);
        }
    }

    public Teacher(String fam, String name, String otch, Date dateOfBirth, String phoneNumber, ArrayList<Group> groups) {
        super(fam, name, otch, dateOfBirth, phoneNumber);
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    public Teacher(String fam, String name, String otch, Date dateOfBirth, String phoneNumber) {
        super(fam, name, otch, dateOfBirth, phoneNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Teacher{"  + id + " "+
                "groups=" + groups +
                "} " + super.toString();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Teacher(){}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Teacher that = (Teacher) o;
        return this.getId().equals(that.getId());
    }
}
```

**This is my dao Class**

```
@Repository
public class TeacherDaoImlp implements TeacherDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void add(Teacher teacher){
        em.persist(teacher);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Teacher> getTeachersList(){
        CriteriaQuery<Teacher> criteriaQuery = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Teacher.class);
        Root<Teacher> root = criteriaQuery.from(Teacher.class);
        return  em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Teacher teacher) {
        em.merge(teacher);
    }

    @Override
    public Teacher findById(Long teacherId) {
        Teacher teacher = em.find(Teacher.class,teacherId);
        if (teacher==null)
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Teacher with ID = " + teacherId + " not found");
        return teacher;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long teacherId) {
       Teacher teacher = em.find(Teacher.class, teacherId);
       if (teacher != null) em.remove(teacher);
       else throw new EntityNotFoundException("Teacher with ID = " + teacherId + " not found");
    }

}
```

Comment: better to use procedure

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/#introduction-to-full-text).
It is a mix of lucene and hibernate.

Indexed field mapping will look like this:

```
  @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
  private String phoneNumber;
```

And dao method for the search:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
        .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Teacher.class).get();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb
        .keyword()
        .onFields("fam", "name", "otch", "dateOfBirth", "phoneNumber")
        .matching("user text")
        .createQuery();

Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Teacher.class);
List result = jpaQuery.getResultList();
```

**Dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
   <version>5.11.3.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-search-elasticsearch</artifactId>
   <version>5.11.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Which dependencies should i add?

Comment: I've just updated the answer. But you could have a look at http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/